# Windows 10 - no drivers on macbook air

Tags: windows-10, macbook-air

I have MacBook air:

> Model Name:   MacBook Air
>   Model: A1466
>   EMC 2632
>   Model Identifier:   MacBookAir6,2
>   Processor Name: Intel Core i5
>   Processor Speed:    1.3 GHz
>   Number of Processors:   1
>   Total Number of Cores:  2
>   L2 Cache (per Core):    256 KB
>   L3 Cache: 3 MB
>   Memory: 4 GB
>   Boot ROM Version:   MBA61.0099.B19
>   SMC Version (system):   2.13f9

System Software Overview:

> System Version:   OS X 10.8.5 (12F45)
>   Kernel Version:   Darwin 12.5.0
>   Boot Volume:  OS X
>   Boot Mode:  Normal

I have installed windows 10 pro version 1803 on macbook air. Now I don't have several critical drivers - among them also driver for wireless card.

Drivers missing:

> - Buletooth USB Host Controller
> - Multimedia controller
> - Network controller
> - PCI simple communications controller
> - SM bus controller

I really don't where to get those drivers? What have I missed?

Before windows 10 I've had windows 8.1 - I've run win 10 ISO file from windows system to upgrade to windows 10.

Comment: Which MacBook Air, most importantly. Not all are supported for Win10.

Comment: I've edited my question with this data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess, but as you don't appear to have ever updated the macOS since you got the machine, the version of Boot Camp is too old to even know what Windows 10 is.

Update the Mac to current macOS 10.13 & it should update Boot Camp to match.

With any significant change, but especially with such a huge jump in OS, solid, tested backups are essential before you start.

Comment: But will this work if windows 10 is already installed?

Comment: tbh, I'm not certain, I kept my only true BC as Win7 & imported it to Parallels to mess with updates. Boot Camp was never designed to be a total replacement for 'a PC'. The Windows install has no 'real' structure & was meant to be disposable, rather than upgradeable. Take the fact that Apple made no provision to even change the volume size once created - that was left to companies like TwoCanoes & Paragon to implement.

Comment: I understand. My original intention was to completely remove Mac OS and leaving only windows. But I guess this is a problem if windows needs mac OS for drivers?